# Are questions about batteries/emergency power on-topic or off-topic?

Tags: discussion

The ARRL has a book called [Emergency Power for Radio Communications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0872599531).

What does the community think?

Answer (score 14):

Given the popularity of Field Day and the continuous discussion about batteries on SOTA and QRP lists, I think it is on-topic.

Comment: Let alone emergency communications, which we [already have three questions about](http://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/emergency).

Answer (score 5):

I'd be inclined to say that if they clearly have a radio connotation (e.g. "what kind of battery pack(s) do I need to run my XYZ rig for at least a day"), they're fine.

More general power questions (e.g. "how many watts can I expect to get out of XYZ solar panel in cloudy conditions") are probably off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

Batteries are an integral part of any portable station, so radio related battery questions have a place.

But the question needs to be focussed: IMHO [Battery capacity vs. weight for portable transceivers](https://ham.stackexchange.com/questions/121/battery-capacity-vs-weight) is not a good question and will lead to opinion-based answers as there is no definitive one.

Comment: Are you sure that there is no definitive one? Battery technologies are measureable and can be compared without opinion.

Comment: It's not answerable without taking into account cost and availability (both of battery and charging equipment). It's also little mor ethan a disguised "What is the best..." question